# Prove that $\overline{A} - A \subset \partial A$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $\overline{A}-A \subset \partial A$

I did the following:

Let $x \in \overline{A}$ $\wedge x \not \in  A $

$\forall r_x>0$ $\{B(x,r_x) \cap \overline{A} \not = \emptyset\}$

$\implies \forall r_x>0$ $\{B(x,r_x) - \{x\}\cap \overline{A} \not = \emptyset\}$

$\implies \forall r_x>0$ $\{B(x,r_x) - \{x\}\cap  \partial A \not = \emptyset\}$

$\implies x \in  \partial A$

$\therefore \overline{A}-A \subset  \partial A$

Comment: What is your definition of $\partial A$ for a subset $A$ of a topological space?

Answer (score 1):

definitions used:
Let A be a subset of a metric space (M,d).

1. $\overline A:=\{p\in M \mid \exists \delta\gt 0 \;\text{such that} \;B(p,\delta)\cap A\ne \emptyset\}$
2. $\partial A:=\{p\in M \mid \forall \delta\gt 0, B(p,\delta)\cap A\ne \emptyset, B(p,\delta)\cap (M-A)\ne \emptyset\}$

$\overline A -A$ may or may not contain points in $M-A$, if it doesn't, then it's the empty set $\emptyset \subset \partial A;$ if it does, then $\exists \delta'\gt 0 \;\text{such that} \;B(p,\delta')\cap A\ne \emptyset,B(p,\delta')\cap (M-A)\ne \emptyset$, which makes $\partial A$ clearly a subset of $\overline A -A$.